# Strange Google Maps v3 geocode behavior when a quote is in the address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

See my [test page](http://tinyurl.com/2enrfgf).

When on the page, click the top left button "Geocode". If you are in Firefox, geocoder.geocode() will have it's status equal to ERROR (and pop an alert after a few seconds). In Internet Explorer (at least 7), everything is fine and the marker is added to the map.

If you remove the quote from the address (l'Assomption --> lAssomption), everything execute fine in Firefox.

Now with my question: how a quote can "crash" the Google Maps V3 API **only in Firefox**!?

**UPDATE:** Status of [my report](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2348) has beed changed to "Confirmed" by Google. It seems it's really a V3 bug. While it's fixed, I remove quotes from the address before geocoding (Google Maps is smart enough to find it without it).

Comment: I can replicate the problem (FF 3.6.3 OS X)... code looks fine to me.  Unfortunately FireBug doesn't record the request/response of the failed call, only successful ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird.  When I try it in Firefox the response code from the server is 403.  Here's test link to the API call as reported in Firebug

[5415 boul. de l'Assomption, Montreal, Quebec, H1T2M4, Canada](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?1m2&1s5415%20boul.%20de%20l%27Assomption%2C%20Montreal%2C%20Quebec%2C%20H1T2M4%2C%20Canada&4sUS&2m1&1sen-US&callback=_xdc_._4nb8by&token=57690)

So, then I loaded it up in IE and fired up [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Here's the link to the API call generated by IE.

[5415 boul. de l'Assomption, Montreal, Quebec, H1T2M4, Canada](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?1m2&1s5415%20boul.%20de%20l'Assomption%2C%20Montreal%2C%20Quebec%2C%20H1T2M4%2C%20Canada&4sUS&2m1&1sen-US&callback=_xdc_._4nb8by&token=57690)

See the difference? Firefox is encoding the `'` into `%27` whereas IE is not.

Conclusions

1. Either a native function or a difference in browser handling by the Google API, Firefox and IE handle the escaping of the apostrophe in URLs differently.
2. Google's geocode service endpoint doesn't know how to handle a URL-encoded apostrophe, and throws a `403 - Forbidden` as a false negative.

Long story short?  Seems like a bug.

Comment: Filled a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2348 we will see what they says...